# iPhone simulator not showing properly on external display

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I started learning to develop apps for the iPhone, and bought my first mac 2 months ago. So I don't know everything about mac os x.

But my question is when I run the iPhone simulator on my laptop (macbook pro retina 13 inch) it shows the iPhone just fine. But when I connect my macbook to my external display, the simulated iPhone doesn't display correctly.

Screenshot of external display:

[image: Valid XHTML]

Is it possible to show the simulator fully/correctly on my external display? Like this (this is on my laptop screen):

[image: Valid XHTML]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the simulator if for a non-retina iPhone, and the other one for a Retina one. That's doesn't mean anything about the resolution fo your laptop vs the external display one.

Comment: I only got retina iPhone's in my list. And I select the same, al iPhone retina 4 inch

Comment: The view doesn't fit (obviously).  You can adjust the "zoom" of the display to make it fit (though frankly the result is often less than pleasing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be change scale size of the simulator

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the vertical resolution on your external monitor is less than on your laptop.  If you increase the vertical resolution, the simulator should display properly.

Comment: You can also use scale to zoom to 100%, 75% or 50% (I often use the 50% which is for most use case enough).